# Does anyone know how to access an application-restricted endpoint HMRC API using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, api

I'm trying to access the "hello application" endpoint using this tutorial: https://developer.service.hmrc.gov.uk/api-documentation/docs/tutorials . The first thing I've tried to do is request the access token but I'm unable to, I'm not quite sure what code I'm missing.

Here's what I've written so far:

```
const clientID = "R4c8CigzdVxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
const clientSecret = "7dba1625-32f5-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx"; 
var url = ("https://test-api.service.hmrc.gov.uk/hello/application");

function hmrcApi() {
  var oauthClientRequest = {
     "tokenLocation": "https://test-api.service.hmrc.gov.uk/oauth/token",
     "grantType": "GrantType.CLIENT_CREDENTIALS",
     "clientID": clientID,
     "clientSecret": clientSecret,
     "setScope": "hello",
     "redirectUri": "https://developer.service.hmrc.gov.uk/api-documentation/docs/api",
     }

  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch (oauthClientRequest);
  var result = JSON.parse(response);
  Logger.log(response.getResponseCode());
}
```

Comment: The redirect URI has to point to an endpoint you control so that you can receive the token. Maybe this helps to understand how oauth works: https://aaronparecki.com/oauth-2-simplified/

Comment: Judging from the API docs not mentioning web-JS you might not be able to use this inside a browser directly. Probably because once you publish the website, anybody can see your credentials. Move that code to a node.js or PHP backend and route relevant info to your frontend-JS.

Comment: Thanks @ChrisG , I will check with HMRC that this doesn't create a problem security wise when using their APIs in JS

Comment: Thanks @FelixKling , we were successful in accessing the token!

Comment: Happy to hear that :)